# javascript how to open a pdf file in a remote server

Tags: javascript, pdf, get, remote-server

I want to open a pdf file in a window using javascript. The file is in a remote server and the path is /bd1/sgacp/sigcp/tempECALCP/survey15es.pdf.

I wrote the following function

```
function leerServerFile(){
     console.log('principio de leerServerFile');
     var request = $.ajax({
         type:    "GET",
         url:"/bd1/sgacp/sigcp/tempECALCP/survey15es.pdf",
         onSuccess:function(response){
             console.log("leerServerfile response ",response);
             //The response text is available in the 'response' variable
             //Set the value of the textarea with the id 'csvResponse' to the response
             $("file-content").value = response;
         }
     });

    }
```

How do I have to write the url the file in the remote server?

The path is /bd1/sgacp/sigcp/tempECALCP/survey15es.pdf

Comment: you want to download the pdf file?

Comment: Open a window, tab or iframe using the pdf URL. Then users like myself who configured their browser to open pdf files in Adobe reader get to read it how they want to.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax restrictions of same origin forbid you to do that. 
Fear not: just use an iframe like this:

```
<iframe src="REMOTESERVERPATH/bd1/sgacp/sigcp/tempECALCP/survey15es.pdf"></iframe>
```